Additive inverse in a Field $\Bbb Z_2$ with 2 elements 0 and 1
In the Appendix C from the book Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, Spence (5th Edition)
Example 4:
The field $\Bbb Z_2$ consists of two elements $0$ and $1$ with the operations of addition and multiplication defined by the equations:

0+0=0, 0+1=1+0=1, 1+1=0,
00=0, 01=1*0=0, and 1.1=1

I couldn't understand 1+1=0
Could someone help me here?

Do you know about the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for integer $n$?

Suppose $1+1=1$. Then $1+0=1+1$ so $0=1$. This makes no sense. Therefore, we must have $1+1=0$.

Maybe these definitions would be clearer to you if you replaced every instance of $0$ with “even” and every instance of $1$ with “odd”: ${\mathbb Z}_2$ consists of two elements, even and odd, satisfying even+even=even, even+odd=odd…..

@JamieRadcliffe My problem is with general intuitiveness. How come 1 + 1 not be 2 and then Z₂ is not a Field at all as per the criteria that a, b belonging to F, then a + b must also belong to F.

@SeanRoberson no, I don't. Could you please explain in brief or share a pointer?

Cf. wikipedia

The notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ refers to the integers modulo $n$. This is the remainder after dividing by n. For example, $19 \mod 4 = 3$ because $19 = 4\cdot 4 + 3.$ So, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ looks at remainder when dividing by $2$.
We know $2 | 2$ so that remainder is zero. Hence, in $\mathbb{Z}_2, \ 2 \mod 2 = 0$ and $1 + 1 =0.$
You may want to read on modular arithmetic.

Thanks @SeanRoberson!
